Literature on implementing pedagogy in teaching
It seems to be fairly well-known that pedagogies are not a set of well-defined constructs that only require a plug-and-play model for implementation. Recently, an anonymous reviewer who reviewed something that I had written, suggested to me that "there is decades of work that looks at issues of implementation of pedagogy". Unfortunately my search did not find anything on this topic in the literature. I found articles that investigated reasons teachers might not be willing to implement new pedagogy, but that's not what I am looking for. Assuming that a teacher is willing to implement a specific pedagogy that has worked well elsewhere, what are some issues that could potentially prevent this pedagogy from working well for them? Do you know any research that has addressed this question?

"Assuming that a teacher is willing to implement a specific pedagogy that has worked well elsewhere, what are some issues that could potentially prevent this pedagogy from working well for them? " Different cultural norms, school/university/college policies, government education policies with regards to maths, uncertainty of outcome of new teaching methods due to limited implementation (and therefore limited known results of said teaching methods) elsewhere. Jo Boaler has quite a bit to say about this in her books when it comes to maths teaching in classrooms in the US.

@AdamRubinson Thank you. Can you suggest a specific book by Jo Boaler, where she discusses the issues that you mentioned? Most of her books are about mindset, which is of course also related to my question, but it will be helpful to know in which book she discusses issues concerning implementation of pedagogy.

I'm thinking of her book, "What's math got to do with it?"
